# if input field has a value found in array, do this (jQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a page with a handful of input fields.

I need to find the fields with an array of values, and if so, `.remove()` the `closest('tr')`

The markup is similar to this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="this">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="that">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="them">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to find "this" and "that", and if they are there, remove their `<tr>` container (and themselves) so I'd end up with:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="them">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var badfields = ['this', 'that'];
    var fieldvalue = $('input[type="text"]').val();

    if($.inArray(fieldvalue, badfields) > -1){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();   
    }
});
```

but it doesn't seem to want to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over all the fields using `.each`, so something like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    var fieldvalue = $(this).val();

    if ($.inArray(fieldvalue, badfields) > -1) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();   
    }
});
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpVrG/)

Comment: why not use `.parent("tr")` instead of `.closest`? `.parent` conveys greater intention IMO

Comment: @JoshE Because I tried to edit the OP's code as little as possible to make it work. You're correct, `.parent` does convey greater intention, but I'd rather not confuse anybody by changing too much at once.

Comment: I ended up using `.parent()` - for some reason I though only closest could traverse up more than 1 element. Other than that, it works beautifully! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can be very concise sometimes with jQuery. jQuery has content selectors you can use for this type of purpose:

`$("input[type=text][value=this], [value=that]").parents("tr").remove();`

since you don't necessarily know `this` or `that` beforehand, you can do something like this:

```
var badfields = ['this', 'that'];
$(badfields).each(function(i) { 
    $("input[type=text][value=" + this + "]").parents("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: This works if you know the values beforehand, or want to generate the selector string yourself, but isn't so great for more general solutions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use each to iterate through the selector. `this` in your `inArray` scope is not the element you were looking for.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/

html:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <input type="text" value="this">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text" value="that">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text" value="them">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var badfields = ['this', 'that'];
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        if( $.inArray(this.value, badfields) > -1 ){
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```